# Top 100 sum with row number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ranking, row-number

I have select:

```
select col1,col2,col3.....sum(colx) from t1 group by col1,col2,col3...
```

How to:

1- display top 100 rows with highest sum(colx1) ordered ASC

2- add row numbers

[image]

Comment: Looks like homework to me. What have you tried and what exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: what happens when two groups have the same sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `TOP()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT TOP 100 t.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sum_col DESC) as row_number 
FROM(
    select col1,col2,col3.....
           sum(colx) as sum_col
    from t1 
    group by col1,col2,col3...) t
ORDER BY sum_col
```

Comment: -> why at the end is "ORDER BY sum_col ", if exactly the same we have I think into "OVER(ORDER BY sum_col DESC)"

Comment: @4est the order by in the `OVER()` clause is to get the row number, its a field that have to be filled. The last order by is to get the `TOP 100` ordered by the `SUM` asc

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` and `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP(100)
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    SUM(colx),
    Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(colx) DESC)
FROM t1
GROUP BY
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
ORDER BY Rn
```

Comment: The inner order by should be DESC.

Comment: I don't see diffrence after I removed "order by RN"